# gzip file write

Tags: android, file-io, gzip, android-file

I have an url with gz file and i need to donload and save this file in phone memory. and in case there is no internet connection i need to read file form memory

```
public Document getDoc(String url1) throws IOException{
      Document document = null;

      try {
            URL url = new URL(url1);


            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            GZIPInputStream zin;
            try {
                zin = (GZIPInputStream)in;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                zin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
            }

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
             document = db.parse(zin);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        } catch(Exception e) {
           // Log.v(TAG, "Exception = " + e);
        }
      return document;
  }
```

Comment: i need to donload and save this file in phone memory  and in case there is no internet connection i need to read file form memory

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the file to your device, save it, and access it later when you need to.

Here's a good tutorial on how to do this: [Working with Files](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html)

Also the Android's documentation: [Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)